# How to create logout functionality of MODX Template with Referral URL instead of defining the MODX template ID?

Tags: url, modx, http-referer

I am trying to use the Referrer URL (Last page user came from) in a MODX template, instead of the MODX Template ID. Does anyone know how to use the Referral URL instead of a template ID Defined in MODX?

I am creating a logging out functionality that I want to close the session and then take the user back to the referral URL. So let's say a user came to my site from another site, I would like them to go back to their site after they logged out from my site?

Comment: I forgot to mention I am creating a logging out functionality that I want to enforce the logout functionality to close the session and then take the user back to the referral url. So let's say a user came to my site from another site, I would like them to go back to their site after they logged out from my site?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to get the referrer (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) when the user first hits your site & store that in a session variable or cookie then either write a script or post hook for the login script that grabs and redirects the user.

however, you can't really trust the http_referrer as it's set by the agent, or in the event that there is no referrer [your is the first site visited]